# Aggregate values over time in temporal table

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

Recently we started using temporal tables feature in MSSQL. Now our analytics department wants to write query aggregating data on per month basis.

Let's say we have table

```
    +----+-------+------------+------------+
    | Id | Value | BeginDate  | EndDate    |
    +------------+------------+------------+
    | 1  | 10    | 2019-12-24 | 9999-12-31 |
    +------------+------------+------------+
    | 1  | 20    | 2019-12-05 | 2019-12-24 |
    +------------+------------+------------+
    | 1  | 40    | 2019-11-05 | 2019-12-05 |
    +----+-------+------------+------------+
```

And now I would like to know average value of `Value` on per month basis. Is that even possible with MSSQL temporal tables? Is it possible to somehow calculate those values (for example `avg(5/31 * 40 + 19/31 * 20 + 7/31 * 10)` for December) automatically and then return them in following format

```
    +----+-------+-------+------+
    | Id | Avg   | Month | Year |
    +------------+--------------+
    | 1  | 15,16 | 12    | 2019 |
    +----+-------+-------+------+
```

Comment: I believe what you need is described here: [Using views with AS-OF sub-clause in temporal queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15#using-views-with-as-of-sub-clause-in-temporal-queries)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward. You can query the data from your temporal tables using the [FOR SYSTEM_TIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15#query-for-changes-to-specific-rows-over-time) clause to return the history of each record, then simply use [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to identify the month and aggregate using GROUP BY. You can see an example of [this here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b54c2d9f046572d3d5cd95db00ae62eb), using SECOND instead of MONTH to group on because I can't insert literal datetime values in the temporal date fields.

Suitable code for MONTH would be:

```
SELECT ID, Year, Month, AVG(Value) AS AvgValue
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, Value, DATEPART(MONTH, BeginDate) AS Month, DATEPART(YEAR, BeginDate) AS Year
  FROM TemporalData
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
) s
GROUP BY ID, Month, Year
```

Comment: Well, that looks easy indeed. What I'm unsure of is if it handles the time spans overlapping for example two months? You're grouping by `DATEPART(MONTH, BeginDate)` but what if `DATEPART(MONTH, BeginDate)` is different than `DATEPART(MONTH, EndDate)`? Will this query still behave as expected?

Comment: Another thing to consider is following situation - `BeginDate = 2010-01-01` and `EndDate = 2019-01-01`. Is there any way for this query to produce rows not only for `2010-01-01`, but also for every month in between those two dates?

Comment: "_I can't insert literal datetime values in the temporal date fields_". [Are you sure about that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e596c0fdd63857c5097e78cdfa25e270)? ;)

Comment: @PeterVandivier Cool, I didn't realise you could do that, I was auto-generating the system versioning fields during table creation. It works for generating test data, but once you enable the system versioning you can no longer do direct inserts.

Comment: @PawełHemperek You need to decide how you want to aggregate your data. For example, do you want the averages of data based on begin month or end month, or only records that occurred inside a single month. It depends on what the data actually is as to the most appropriate way of aggregating it.

Comment: @PawełHemperek To your second question, you can use the CONTAINED IN clause (see first link in my answer) to limit to records that have a begin & end date inside 2010 only. See this [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe4967e67498077effe12d6702842500). (Thanks to Peter Vandivier for the updated fiddle).

Comment: @HandyD "_...but once you enable the system versioning you can no longer do direct inserts._" [Are you sure about that?](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36aa87c9cddcac1dd892d88da6fcb3c5) ;)

Comment: @PeterVandivier Hahaha, twice in the same thread! It's good to know it can be done.